# Check if all letters in Small-String are contained in Large-String

Tags: r, string-matching, textmatching

I am trying to write some code to determine if the letters in a small string are contained in a larger string in R. The Accuracy would then be returned by a percentage.

I found the following on StackOverflow ([check if all characters of one string exist in another string in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085290/check-if-all-characters-of-one-string-exist-in-another-string-in-r)), but the code provided calculates the average as the count of unique overlap divided by count of unique letters.
i.e. it does not allow for repeated letters

```
s1 <- "ABBDEFGHIZ"
s2 <- "ABBDEFGHIJ"

compare <- function(s1, s2) {
  c1 <- unique(strsplit(s1, "")[[1]])
  c2 <- unique(strsplit(s2, "")[[1]])
  length(intersect(c1,c2))/length(c1)
}

compare(s1,s2)
[1] 0.8888889
```

Ideally, the above code should return a value of 0.9, as 9/10 of the letters are matched instead of 8/9.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Such function already exist. Try `RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim(s1, s2)`

Comment: Thanks Sotos. I had used other metrics such as JW, but found flaws with them. This levenshteinSim works in some instances - however, upon checking some of my data. I had the following issue:

Answer (score -1):

something like this:

```
compare <- function(s1, s2) {
  c1 <- strsplit(s1, "")[[1]]
  c2 <- strsplit(s2, "")[[1]]
  x=sum(c1%in%c2)
  x/length(unique(c(c1,c2)))
}
```